# PHP regex to search in the exact given pattern

Tags: php, regex

i want to give regex a pattern and force it to read it all ..

`http://example.com/w/2/1/x/some-12345_x.png`

i want to target "some-12345_x"
i used this `/\/(.*).png/`, it doesnt work for some reason

how do i force it to remember it must start with / and end with .png?

Comment: Is regexing for `/some-12345_x.png` and then substringing to `some-12345_x`an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always want to get the final file-name, minus the extension, you could use PHP's `substr()` instead of trying to come up with a regex:

```
$lastSlash = strrpos($url, '/') + 1;
$name = substr($url, $lastSlash, strrpos($url, '.') - $lastSlash);
```

Also, a more readable method would be to use PHP's `basename()`:

```
$filename = basename($url);
$name = substr($filename, 0, strpos($filename, '.'));
```

To actually use a regex, you could use the following pattern:

```
.*/([^.]+).png$
```

To use this with PHP's `preg_match()`:

```
preg_match('|.*/([^.]+).png$|', $url, $matches);
$name = $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
^.*/(.*)\.png$
```

which captures what occurres after the last `/` till `.png` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use reg-ex in this situation for a particular reason, but here's an alternative where you don't:

```
$url = "http://example.com/w/2/1/x/some-12345_x.png";
$value = pathinfo($url);
echo $value['filename'];
```

output:

```
some-12345_x
```

[pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) from the manual

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
~([^/]+)\.png$~
```

this will match anything but `/` until `.png` at the end of the string.